# I am importing bulma in laravel project but the styling is not working

Tags: php, laravel, sass, bulma

I have installed bulma using npm in my laravel project and I have imported it in app.scss file but its not working.

I have compiled the project using nmp run dev and npm run watch. I cant understand whats the problem

```
@import 'node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';

@import './node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass';

@import 'node_modules/buefy/src/scss/buefy';
```

this is app.scss file of my Laravel project

Bulma should work properly

Answer (score 0):

I found a way I guess I was doing it manually that is why I messed up so I found about the laravel front-end presets so I configure it using

composer require laravel-frontend-presets/bulma